# When talking to the child of a same sex couple, is it more standard to say "your parents" or "your fathers"/"your mothers"?

Tags: kinship-terms, grammatical-gender, sexual-minorities

When talking about an opposite sex couple, it's standard to talk about "your parents", because it's a lot less wordy than "your mother and father". But what's more standard for a same sex couple? "Your parents", or "Your mothers"/"Your fathers"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linguistically, there is no normal here. Come back in 50 years.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, there's no standard for it as yet. As the number of same-sex couples increases, we are likely to see whether any form emerges as a standard. For the time being, I for one would tend to follow the child's or the couple's forms of address: fathers, mothers, parents. Lacking that information, I'd just go for "your parents".